# How to unset focus on an input after keyup.enter event in Vuejs?

Tags: vue.js

How to unset input focus after `keyup.enter` event ?

```
<v-text-field v-on:keyup.enter="onPageChange"></v-text-field>
```

My goal to prevent the suggestions popup which hides a table behind.

Comment: you can call `blur()` inside `onPageChange` at the end. have you tried that?

Comment: How do you call `blur()` inside `onPageChange` ?

Comment: pass `$event` to the onPageChange like `onPageChange($event)` n then in code just call `event.target.blur();` or `event.currentTarget.blur()`

Comment: It doesn't hide the popup.

Comment: Does it unset focus from the input box?

Comment: I didn't refresh correctly, it works perfect, thanks. Why not make an answer with this suggestion ?

Comment: Sure. will do that in a minute to help future users too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To unset focus on input after `keyup.enter` the event, first pass the `$event` object to the function like:

```
<v-text-field v-on:keyup.enter="onPageChange($event)">
</v-text-field>
```

Then in the `onPageChange()` method call [`blur()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/blur) method based on the `event` target like:

```
onPageChange(event){
   // Your rest of the code here..

   // finally call blur() like:
   event.target.blur(); 
}
```